# connect to nginx(aws ecs) to postgresql rds and show tables "info" in main web page

Tags: python-3.x, docker, psycopg2

i use this dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install psycopg2-binary
COPY list_tables.py /usr/share/nginx/html/
RUN chmod +x /usr/share/nginx/html/list_tables.py
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo \"Tables: $(python3 /usr/share/nginx/html/list_tables.py)\" >    /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

and this script:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(
host="your_postgresql_host",
database="your_database",
user="your_username",
password="your_password"
)
    
cur = conn.cursor()
    
cur.execute("SELECT info FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'")
    
tables = [table[0] for table in cur.fetchall()]
    
cur.close()
conn.close()
    
print(tables)
```

but my service is always not working
i check all script but can't find mistakes